# Flutter : CircularProgressIndicator keep in center inside Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I am a newbie for Flutter Development, I have created a sample demo to get JSON from Server and Bind in `ListView`, I have done it successfully.

Now I want to show **CircularProgressIndicator()** in the center of the screen while loading the list.

I have tried many ways like **Expanded**, **Flexible**, **Stack** but didn't get succeed.

You can check the full code here: **[main.dart](https://github.com/pratikbutani/FlutterPinCodeFinder/blob/master/lib/main.dart)**

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone help me to keep `CircularProgressIndicator` in the center?

Answer (score 2):

Use this approach:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    TextField(),  // Your text field. 
    Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach:

```
        Column(
          children: [
            TextField(), // Your text field.
            Spacer(),
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
```